# Is there a way I can filter by any one of x in a django query

Tags: python, django, list, django-queryset

In my webwapp, I would like the user to be able to filter search results by selecting categories from the [sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILQRR.png).

The data GET request in the view retrieves the list of selected options and are parsed out. This data to filter by is then separated into lists, as shown in the following snippet from Index in views.py:

```
class Index(View):
    def get(request):
        ... some checks to ensure its a valid request...
        if valid:
            dietTypeList = request.GET.getlist('diettype[]') #['meat','vegetarian',...] 
            categoryList = request.GET.getlist('categories[]') #['Italian','Western',...]
            ....
            return render(request,'results.html',context_dict)
        ....
```

I would then like to filter the results within the `.filter()` filter function so that my results are any of the selected categories, with any of the dietary types applied to those categories.

I have looked into Q queries however im not sure how to do the following in any case
How do I effectively do the following:

```
results = Recipe.objects.filter(Q(name__contains=searchCriteria) & Q(category=any of categoryTypeList ))
```

Comment: Am I missing something if I suggest `category__in=[category, list]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to create a filter to see if a category is a member of a set of categories would be to use the [double-underscore `name__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups) form for field lookups, as in

```
results = Recipe.objects.filter(category__in=some_set_of_categories)
```